# How to return $this in a php Extension?

Tags: php, c++, php-extension

For example this method of `Dataset` object returns `NULL`, How do I make it to return `$this`

```
PHP_METHOD(TSet, nextLine)
{
    TSet *MySet;
    tset_object *obj = (tset_object *)zend_object_store_get_object(getThis() TSRMLS_CC);
    MySet = obj->DataSet;
    if (MySet != NULL) {
        MySet->nextLine();
    }
    RETURN_NULL();
}
```

Tried

```
zval *object = getThis();
RETURN_ZVAL(object,false,false);
```

Gave me segfault
And just to be sure also this

```
RETURN_ZVAL(getThis(),false,false);
```

With same result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RETURN_ZVAL(getThis(), 1, 0);

Is the correct answer, not sure why though.
Got it from http://www.snailinaturtleneck.com/blog/2011/08/11/php-extensions-made-eldrich-classes/#comment-466980122